# How to pass optional parameter in stored procedure in my case in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I am trying to pass optional variable. User may pass value or may not be passed.

What I tried:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spSampleProc
    @Alias NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
    @CountDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        ST
    INNER JOIN
        Item ON Item.id = st.itemid
    LEFT JOIN
        PIC_User ON ST.HandHeldNo = PIC_User.ID
    LEFT JOIN
        ViewRecord AS Alias ON Alias.itemid = item.ID
    LEFT JOIN
        Department ON Department.ID = item.DepartmentID
    LEFT JOIN
        Category ON category.id = item.CategoryID
    WHERE
        (@Alias IS NULL OR (Alias.Alias LIKE '%' + @Alias + '%'))
        AND ST.Date >= @CountDate
END
```

Running it:

```
EXEC spSampleProc @CountDate = '2018/09/01' @Alias = '6281063633419'
```

I've created a stored procedure without any syntax error. But when I execute the procedure, it throws the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@Alias'.

Comment: You missed the comma between parameters on the EXE statement. Also, you need a GO after END so that the proc call call itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma between the two parameters:

```
Exec spSampleProc @CountDate='2018/09/01', @Alias='6281063633419'
-- Here ---------------------------------^
```